# OpenSL channel selection

Tags: android, opensl

I have to play a single channel from an ogg file under Android. After a lot of searching, I think I found out a strategy.

Using OpenSL, I decode the file to PCM using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863797/1924721).
Then I should copy the selected channel from the PCM buffer into another buffer linked to the OutputMix, using something like [this](https://gist.github.com/hrydgard/3072540).

Is this the best option? Is there something already available to look at?

Thank you.

Comment: I solved using non-native code based on https://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using non-native code based on [OpenMXPlayer](http://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer).

**Update**: The general idea is to use `MediaCodec` to decode the file to memory, than modify the data in memory, than send it to an `AudioTrack`.