# AudioTrack unable to control Headphone sound in either side

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm, audiotrack

I am working on AudioTrack Pcm sound generation. I am trying to control volume for either side of the earpiece in the headphone via setStereoVolume() method i.e only one side of the headphone need to hear. But unable to completely stop the sound in the other side of the headphone.

Comment: [`setStereoVolume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#setStereoVolume(float,%20float)) looks like it’s deprecated. Frustratingly, you may need to use [OpenSL ES](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl/)

Comment: @fdcpp thanks. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Start here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863797/8876321

Comment: @fdcpp thank you I will try it. I am new to NDK